# Is it possible to have a const reference to a nonconst char pointer?

Tags: pointers, reference

Is it possible to have a `const` reference to `*argv` and iterate through the array of pointers `argv`?

For the code below, I get the following warning:

> a reference of type "const char *& (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "char *"

After building, I get this error message:

> cannot convert from 'char *' to 'const char *&'.

```
#import <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main (int argc, char * argv []) {
    for (const char *& c = *argv; *c != '\0'; ++c) {
        cout << *c << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am confused because I know it is possible to have a `const` reference to a `non-const` variable like so:

```
int  i = 42;
int &r1 = i;
```

Comment: Yes, sorry my question was poorly worded. I did run this code and received the following error: a reference of type "const char *& (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "char *". I am not sure how to interpret this message. Does this mean that my syntax is wrong or that is not possible to have a const reference to *argv?